# simple join causing huge number of rows to be used

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do what I think is a simple join between two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE t_slv
(
    symbol_id       int                     NOT NULL,
    load_id         SMALLINT,
    val                     DECIMAL(10,4)   NOT NULL,
    -- PRIMARY KEY ( symbol_id )
    unique index ( symbol_id )
);

CREATE TABLE nasd (
    symbol_id       integer                 NOT NULL, 
    load_id         SMALLINT                NOT NULL,
    openp           DECIMAL(10,4)   NOT NULL,   -- range 0.0001 - 999,999.9999
    high            DECIMAL(10,4)   NOT NULL,
    low                     DECIMAL(10,4)   NOT NULL,
    last            DECIMAL(10,4)   NOT NULL,
    volume          integer                 NOT NULL
    -- PRIMARY KEY ( symbol_id, load_id )
    -- INDEX ( load_id )
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX nasd_1_ix1 on nasd( symbol_id, load_id );
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX nasd_1_ix2 on nasd( load_id, symbol_id );
```

So, when I do this :

```
mysql> explain                 select  nasd.load_id
  ->                         -- nasd.low
->                 from    t_slv,
->                         nasd
->                 where   t_slv.symbol_id = nasd.symbol_id
->                         and nasd.load_id >= 4700
->                         and nasd.load_id <= 4917 ;
      +----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------+------------+---------+--------    --------------+---------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys         | key        | key_len |   ref                  | rows    | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------+------------+---------+----------------------+---------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t_slv | index | symbol_id             | symbol_id  | 4       | NULL                 |       1 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | nasd  | ref   | nasd_1_ix1,nasd_1_ix2 | nasd_1_ix1 | 4       | prog.t_slv.symbol_id | 2069669 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------+------------+---------+----------------------+---------+--------------------------+
```

2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Sorry this is so hard to read.

If t_slv has only one row in it, just joining it to nasd causes over 2 million rows to be accessed.  If I take t_slv out and just do a straight select from table nasd, only 217 rows are accessed - which makes sense because that is how many rows there are between 4700 and 4917.

So, just joining to one table with one row causes an explosion in rows accessed, even though it is using the same index as it would if t_slv is not in the join.

Does this make sense to anybody?

The real life situation is actually worse - if t_slv has 1000 rows in it the select takes 20 minutes, which essentially makes it not runnable.

Even if I force the index, I am quite sure I get the same result.  Meaning, even though it is using the index, it is accessing millions of rows.

TIA.

Don

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql thinks there is only one row in `t_slv`, so it thinks it is fine to grab that one row, grab `symbol_id` out of it, then use the `nasd_1_ix1` index to find all the matching rows.  Its 2M row *guess* as to how many rows match in `nasd` is an artifact of the fact that the `symbol_id,load_id` index is not unique, so it has no way of knowing how many rows are between the ranges you gave.  It will not actually read that many rows given your real data.

Does `t_slv` only have one row?  If not, you might want to rebuild that table so mysql has an up-to-date understanding of its size.

Even if `t_slv` has many rows, that plan still looks fine because `symbol_id`s are unique in `t_slv`, and there is an index starting with `symbol_id` on `nasd`, so mysql is sure it never has to look at a row twice.

Comment: Oh, got it.  its a guess.  in the example t_slv had only one row, but in reality it has thousands and the join is more complex - I reduced it to basics in order to build it back up again.  Is there a way or a tool to measure how many rows are actually read when a query executes?  that would help out a lot.  I am using percona server, but I am not yet familiar with the tools folks use to tune.  thx again.  -Don

Comment: Oh one other point, and a question.  in the beginning of a complex set of queries, t_slv is cleared and then inserted with symbol_id of those symbols needing a recalculation.  its typically in the 1000's.  so when you say 'rebuild the table so mysql has up-to-date understanding of its size', how can I do that on the fly?  all these queries are in a stored procedure, I start by deleting from t_slv, then inserting.  at that point, should I inform mysql somehow so it has an 'understanding of its size'?